# ASP.NET MVC with ASP.NET Web Api authentication and roles

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I've created an ASP.NET MVC application, i've installed successfully the WebAPI, and now i use ajax request to get the api's data.
Some data should be available only after user authenticates, and only if it is in a certain role. Is there a way to do that?

C# WebApi code:

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize(Roles = RoleTypes.Admin +","+ RoleTypes.Enabled)]
    public string Query()
    {
    string test = "test";
    return test;
    }

}
```

My JavaScript code:

```
  // Here i should get the tokenKey but where should i set it? is this approach right?
var token = sessionStorage.getItem(tokenKey);
var headers = {};
    if (token) {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'Authorization': "Bearer " + token
            }
        });
    }


    $.get("/api/Test/Query", function (data) {
    //stuffs here
      });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw in your code that you use of JWT token.
JWT token made like:

```
XXX.ZZZ.YYY
```

You can in your start up project, get roles and permissions and set in your token, when the user won’t login.

Or create a catching method, to get roles and permissions, and use of static property which you set data in that.

Now, the question in here that how authorize your action user.

I suggest you that use of action filter [use of this link to understanding action filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs), and check their permission and call other pipeline.

GoodLuck.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api), when the user logs in, you should generate a token. This token will be stored in client-side and used in the requests.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Login',
    data: loginData
}).done(function (data) {
    self.user(data.userName);
    // Cache the access token in session storage.
    sessionStorage.setItem(tokenKey, data.access_token);
}).fail(showError);
```

Next, when the user sends the request to the server, you pass your token the header.

```
var token = sessionStorage.getItem(tokenKey);
var headers = {};
if (token) {
    headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + token;
}

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'api/values/1',
    headers: headers
}).done(function (data) {
    //stuffs here
}).fail(showError);
```

Following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api), the token is decrypted in the server to get the claims (roles) to the authorization. Your `ApiController` is correct